# Angular Directive: Point to second element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to refer to a second element in a directive.

Essentially I'd like to resize a textbox based on a dummy div's height.

```
<textarea vertical-align="dummyDiv"></textarea>
<div class="dummyDiv"></div>
```

In the directive, how do I access the attributes of the dummyDiv element?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of one way to access another element outside of a directive.

http://plnkr.co/edit/S8EGeE4Z87jv6UQim6eG?p=preview

```
<textarea vertical-align secondary-elem="'dummyDiv'" ng-model="someScopeValue"></textarea>
<div class="dummyDiv"></div>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myController', function($scope) {
            $scope.someScopeValue = 'Sample Text';
        })
        .directive('verticalAlign', function($parse) {
            return {
                scope: {
                    secondaryElem: '='
                },
                require: '^ngModel',
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    var otherElem = angular.element('.' + scope.secondaryElem);

                    function process(inputValue) {
                        otherElem.text(inputValue);
                    }

                    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(process);

                    console.log(otherElem);
                }
            };
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This is getting there, but I lose access to the ngModel element. If I exclude the scope in the directive, I can still access attr.ngModel, but if I INCLUDE the scope (with secondaryElem) I can't access or watch that ngModel anymore.

Comment: @opticon Can you provide an updated Plunker that shows the issue you are speaking about?